# Php preg_replace substitute not working as expected using Devanagar Unicode string

Tags: php, preg-replace, indic, devanagari

I want to replace Devanagari Unicode characters of specific sequence.

```
$re = '/(कर(?![ािीुूृॄॅेैॉोौ्ऱ्]))/m';
$str = 'समर साकाकरुन भरुन करमरकर';
$subst = '****';
$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```

notice that substitution is **** for every occurrence for कर if these ([ािीुूृॄॅेैॉोौ्ऱ्) characters are not followed to this (कर) pattern.
This works correctly on https://regex101.com/r/WRc04s/1 but not on my WAMP or LAMP setup
Point to note is that this does work as expected using English (Latin) character set.
What could be the issue?

Comment: You need the `u` modifier, `$re = '/कर(?![ािीुूृॄॅेैॉोौ्ऱ्])/u';`

Comment: Wiktor you are my hero. Perfect answer under one minute. Please convert comment to answer so that I can mark it as correct solution.